# C# RegEx to find a specific string or all words in a string

Tags: c#, regex

Looking it up, I thought I understood how to look up a string of multiple words in a sentence, but it does not find a match. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I need to be able to find a single or multiple word match. I passed in "to find" to the method and it did not find the match. Also, if the user does not enclose their search phrase in quotes, I also need it to search on each word entered.

```
var pattern = @"\b\" + searchString + @"\b";    //searchString is passed in.

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

var sentence = "I need to find a string in this sentence!";

Match match = rgx.Match(sentence);

if (match.Success)
{
    // Do something with the match.
}
```

Comment: Why the 2nd backslash in `@"\b\"`?

Comment: Can the individual words be also enclosed with quotes? Like `"theatre" "museum"` (that can match *theatre and museum*) vs. `"theatre museum"` that only matches *theatre museum*? AND what if they contains double (escaped?) quotes? Like `"\"Summer\" trend" "fashion"`?

Comment: It can be like "theatre" "museum" OR theatre museum (no quotes) if a user wants to search on individual words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the second `\` in the first `@"\b\"`:

```
var pattern = @"\b" + searchString + @"\b";
                  ^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/kEDoXA)

Note that in case you have special regex metacharacters (like `(`, `)`, `[`, `+`, `*`, etc.) in your `searchString`s, you can use `Regex.Escape()` to escape them:

```
var pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(searchString) + @"\b";
```

And if those characters may appear in edge positions, use lookarounds rather than word boundaries:

```
var pattern = @"(?<!\w)" + searchString + @"(?=\w)";
```

Comment: Great a typo that I never noticed...those are the worst. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I would not have posted an answer if I had not seen some potential bottleneck with your approach. I hope my additional explanations will be of help. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks again for the additional explanation.

Comment: I need the RegEx to work if the user enters quotes and search for the whole phrase and to also search on each word if no quotes. I've updated my question to make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: For now, please have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/34fe7V). You have not specified the behavior for cases like `"to" find them`: should it look for "to" and "find them", or "to" || "find" || "them", or any other way.

Comment: Between what you already provided and the latest demo, I am able to get what I need. Thank you for your help.