# Finding all matches in a string

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am trying to get exact matches from a list in a longer string, this is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;      
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stringToCheck = "fooX, fooY);";

        List<string> allStrings = new List<string>{
         "fooX",
         "foo",
         "fooY"
        };

        var matches =  allStrings.Where(cmd => stringToCheck.IndexOf(cmd) > -1).ToList();

        //expected output is 2
        Console.Write(matches.Count);
    }  
}
```

Currently I'm getting all 3 strings matching, my question is how to  match the 2 exact matches

For context, the value of the string to check is a string representation of a class file.

Comment: Why does ```var stringToCheck = "fooX, fooY);";``` have ):?

Comment: All 3 filters match the input... if you need exact matches then you will need to perform an exact match on each word.

Comment: 'fooX', 'fooY' are in the string and 'foo' is in the string too. It's a part of both 'fooY' and 'fooX'

Comment: Are you looking for *whole word match*? I.e. `"foo"` doesn't have a match in `"fooX, fooY);"` when `"fooX"` does

Comment: The string "FooBar" contains "Foo", right? or do you want to match on the complete word?

Comment: You can't match words with simple string operations, you need a regular expression

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726629/c-sharp-regex-to-find-a-specific-string-or-all-words-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are looking for *whole word* match; i.e. `"foo"` *doesn't match* `"fooX, fooY);"` since we have `fooX` and `fooY` *whole words* only.

if it's your case, you can use *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var matches = allStrings
  .Where(cmd => Regex.IsMatch(stringToCheck, $@"\b{Regex.Escape(cmd)}\b"))
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** If `allStrings` and `stringToCheck`are long and all items of `allStrings` are guarantee to consist of a..z letters only, you can try a faster solution - split `stringToCheck` into `words`:

```
HashSet<string> words = new HashSet<string>(Regex.Split(stringToCheck, @"\W"));
```

And then check for these precomputed `words`:

```
var matches = allStrings
  .Where(cmd => words.Contains(cmd))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this need to search the complete string for every entry in `allStrings`.

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, in the worse case the entire `stringToCheck` will be scanned for each item in `allStrings`. It's possible to run regular expression just once, but it applies restrictions on `allStrings`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) method instead:

```
var matches = stringToCheck.Split(',').Intersect(allStrings).ToList();
```

But since you have some character in your string `);` you need to do something like this:

```
var matches = string.Join("", stringToCheck.TakeWhile(c => c != ')'))
    .Replace(" ","").Split(',').Intersect(allStrings).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhnKyT

Comment: [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` and compile this expression for a performance boost.

```
      var stringToCheck = "fooX, fooY);";
        List<string> allStrings = new List<string>{
            "fooX",
            "foo",
            "fooY"
        };
        var matches = Regex.Matches(stringToCheck, $@"\b({string.Join('|', allStrings)})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
```